# Select name of column in pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to select the name of the column from which the pivot values comes from in the following pivot...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  filename,
  vals
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        filename,
        a1,
        a2,
        a3
   FROM 
      foo) p
UNPIVOT
   (vals FOR counts IN 
      (a1,a2,a3)
) AS bar
```

So if a value gets select into the vals column but is actually from a3 then I need a3 to be selected into another column within that record. So...

```
   Vals   |   AColName
  235.53      a3
  48.54       a3
  93.49       a1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use counts column in select as follows:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT 
  filename,
  vals,counts
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        filename,
        a1,
        a2,
        a3
   FROM 
      foo) p
UNPIVOT
   (vals FOR counts IN 
      (a1,a2,a3)
) AS bar
```

Comment: You're the man. Sorry new to this stuff, retaining things as I go. Will accept answer as soon as it lets me! Thanks.